# Access to the SSRS server in Dynamics CRM Online 2015

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

Is there a way to access the SSRS server in Dynamics CRM Online 2015 via C# code and access properties like:

- URL of the Reporting Server
- Reports paths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to access SSRS in CRM Online.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I need your help: Can we send reports by email or store them on a server in Dynamics CRM 2015 OnLine? thank you in advance